# ImportError: Start directory is not importable: 'tests' appears on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Any way to fix this issue? I was trying to test this code and thought that everything was in order, but somehow I don't know how this continues to appear.

```
import unittest


class CardTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_setup(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? You can not get into Debug panel?

Comment: Made a mistake with typing the wrong number of the directory.